# How do i convert "dd.mm.yyyy " string to datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby and i need help to convert a string of format "dd.mm.yyyy" to date time.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Date.strptime('03.02.2001', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

**UPDATE**:
This will return a Date object

As David rightfully stated below:

```
DateTime.strptime('03.02.2001', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

will give you a ruby DateTime object.

Comment: DateTime.strptime('03.02.2001', '%d.%m.%Y')